# wxpython GUI freezes while running selenium web driver

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I'm learning GUI design using WXPython and Web Scraping using Selenium. I make a small tool that when I click on the "Start" button it will collect data from a website, calculate the number and print the result back to the GUI. GUI has the statusBar at the bottom to display the status of web browser.

Because the browser has to navigating through 5 different pages to get all the numbers, so I would like to display on the status bar that "Collecting page 1", "Collecting page 2" etc...

The problem is, my GUI just freezes when browser is at page 1, the status page is freezes at "Collecting page 1". If I click on the GUI then its status is "Not Responding". However, when the browser finishes and closes, I got my result back and the GUI is back to normal. (with the statusbar displays "Collecting page 4")

Since im still learning and its my first time doing this, which knowledge should I look into, or how can I make both of them running normally at the same time? Meant that the browser still scrapes the data and the GUI still displaying the statusBar's message (Collecting page 1, collecting page 2 etc...).

Thank you so much!

Update: I read about threads and multi-thread, are those the things that I should look into?

Run-time takes around 12-15 seconds and I get the right result, but the GUI freezes during the process.
I have my MainGUI.MainFrame which contains the GUI, here is the TestGUI class:
Each page contains thousand of data, and i need to do some calculation on them.

```
class TestGUI:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        MainGUI.MainFrame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.statusBar.SetStatusText("Ready to scrape")

    # Button start
    def Start(self, event):
        self.statusBar.SetStatusText("Starting ...")

        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("http://127.0.0.1/customerdata/")
        element = driver.find_element_by_name("customer-id")
        self.statusBar.SetStatusText("Collecting page 1")
        // do something
        element = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("Page 2")
        element[0].click();
        element = driver.find_element_by_name("customer-id")
        self.statusBar.SetStatusText("Collecting page 2")
        // do somthing 
        ....
        // same thing with page 3 and page 4
        self.statusBar.SetStatusText("result:" + str(result))
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post any code. Please read through the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) documentation, and create the smallest self-contained code example possible that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks,  I have added my code which is very simple